# Python Pip Install pyodbc SSLCertVerificationError - [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] - unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

Tags: python, windows, ssl, pip, ssl-certificate

Since yesterday I'm experiencing difficulties installing any new packages through PIP. I`m constantly getting this ssl error, which I have never experienced before:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org.x.a21a7e8f0e3c70499e099e6035cdeac3ac53.9270f642.id.opendns.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /s/files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/b1/e7a3d321144e7701ad0850b82cb727407a273c80d5917a3acd2273ac6ec4/pyodbc-4.0.28-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl?X-OpenDNS-Session=_a21a7e8f0e3c70499e099e6035cdeac3ac539270f6
42_d8yAgKPJ_ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (**_ssl.c:1076**)')))
```

I have gone through all the questions related to SSL errors on pip and I have tried the following:

- Created `pip.ini` file defining `trusted-host = pypi.python.org pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org` and `cert = ~\AppData\Local\pip\cacert.pem`
- I upgraded python from 3.7.4 to 3.7.6
- Upgrade PIP to 20.0.2 and upgrade setuptools to latest version manually as pip does not work
- Run pip install command as: `pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org pyodbc`
- Run pip as follow: `pip --cert ~\AppData\Local\pip\cacert.pem pyodbc`

I tried running this on windows 10 in a virtual environment and I also tried running this from an Ubuntu docker container with absolutely no success.

What else is there for me to try?

Comment: After doing all of the above a good old restart was required